# Share Variable between specific threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I am facing a problem in java wherein my program makes `n` independent threads (of `ClassA`) initially and then each thread of `ClassA` makes `m` dependent threads (`ClassB`). So in total I have now `m.n` threads (of `ClassB`). Now I want to share a variable between the `m` threads (of `ClassB`) created by a specific thread of `ClassA`. I can't use static because then all the `m.n` threads will
share the same variable but I only want the `m` threads created by a specific thread of `ClassA` to share these. Is there any implementation I can follow to do the same?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't you provide a reference for the object you want to share upon instancing all the `ClassB` threads from a `ClassA` thread?

Comment: but doesn't java use pass by value.ok i just looked up and found java use pass by reference for objects

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the shared variable into `B` using its constructor

```
class B extends Thread {
    final private Object shared;

    B(Object obj) {
        shared = obj;
    }
}
```

Now have `A` pass the same object into each `B` that it creates

Comment: You will need to ensure that the object is atomic.

Comment: Yes, the shared object needs to be thread-safe - ideally it would be immutable, as then there's no risk of a deadlock or race condition or whatever

Comment: but then how do i make the m Class b threads share the variable as it value will be changed by each thread.

Comment: Use the Synchronized block, where you will be setting the data for the shared object. In this way, before changing the data, it will need to acquire a lock, or it will wait for the lock to get released.

Comment: This solution will in fact result in the variable being shared, so long as you pass the same object reference to each thread constructor.

Comment: @Joe Dominic Valluvassery If it's an object then have `A` create one object instance and pass a reference to that object to each `B`; if it's an immutable primitive then use an immutable primitive wrapper like `Integer` or `Boolean`, and if it's a mutable primitive then either create your own wrapped primitive or else use one of the `Atomic[Primitive]` classes, e.g. [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here some working code that uses a mutable `ArrayList` as the shared value, each `ClassB` thread adds a 10 numbers to the list and then ends their execution.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FooMain {

    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException {
        FooMain f = new FooMain();
        ClassA a = f.new ClassA(10);
        a.start();
            // Give all the threads some time to finish.
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        for (String x : a.list) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        System.out.println(a.list.size());
    }

    public class ClassA extends Thread {
        public List<String> list;       
        private List<ClassB> threads;

        public ClassA(int m) {
            this.list = new ArrayList<>();
            this.threads = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int i = 0; i < m; i++) {
                this.threads.add(new ClassB(i, this.list));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for (ClassB b : this.threads) {
                b.start();
            }
        }
    }

    public class ClassB extends Thread {
        private List<String> list;
        private int id;

        public ClassB(int id, List<String> list) {
            this.id = id;
            this.list = list;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                synchronized(this.list) {
                    this.list.add("Id:" + Integer.toString(this.id) + " - #: " + Integer.toString(i));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```